# Java lookandfeels that work with SpinnerDateModel

Tags: java, look-and-feel, jspinner

I have a DateSpinner that uses a SpinnerDateModel, and I need the spinner increment to be the day of the month.  This is how I initialize it:

```
new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.DATE));
```

However, it doesn't increment by the day.  I read that certain look and feels (I'm using system look and feel on Windows 7) ignore that Calendar field in the SpinnerDateModel and just use the date field that's selected.  Can anyone suggest a good look and feel that won't do this? Or suggest an alternative way to implement a spinner that increments the date by day?  Can I disable selection of anything but the day field in the spinner or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSpinner time = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
JSpinner.DateEditor dateEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(time, "dd:MM:yy");
time.setEditor(dateEditor);
```

Works fine for me.

Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a little more, I just decided to create a subclass of SpinnerDateModel and override the setCalendarField() function to do nothing, per the suggestion of Michael Dunn found here:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/345684/GUI/java/JSpinner-DateEditor-Set-default-focus